# Хранение конфигов во внешнем файле

Tags: безопасность, ruby-on-rails

В приложении необходимо обращаться к api фэйсбука (omniauth), поэтому нужно хранить secret_key, сейчас он просто прописан в инициализаторе контрллера

```
`config.omniauth :facebook, '111111111', '22222222222'`
```

, хотелось бы вынести в отдельный файл данные настройки. Видел подобное решение:

OAUTH_CREDENTIALS_PATH = "#{ENV['HOME']}/mysite/oauth.yml"
OAUTH_CREDENTIALS = YAML.load_file(OAUTH_CREDENTIALS_PATH)[Rails.env]

но оно у меня не заработало.
Как правильно решить поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ваших задач и конфигов к ним вполне подойдёт гем [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).

Comment: Спасибо, гем для моих задач очень подходит